# Why this error trying to conditionally wrap my actix-web app?

Tags: rust, actix-web

I'm trying to conditionally wrap my app with CORS, but I'm getting errors.

```rust
use actix_cors::Cors;
use actix_web::{http::header, App, HttpServer};
use std::{net::SocketAddr, sync::Arc};

use common::config::Config;

pub async fn start(config: Arc<Config>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let config_app = Arc::clone(&config);

    let server = HttpServer::new(move || {
        let mut app = App::new();

        if config_app.cors.enabled {
            app = app.wrap( // the error is here, read below
                Cors::default()
                    .allowed_origin("http://localhost:8080")
                    .allowed_methods(vec!["GET", "POST"])
                    .allowed_headers(vec![header::AUTHORIZATION, header::ACCEPT])
                    .allowed_header(header::CONTENT_TYPE)
                    .supports_credentials()
                    .max_age(3600),
            )
        }

        app
    });

    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], config.port));

    server.bind(addr)?.run().await
}
```

the error is:

```
mismatched types
expected struct `actix_web::App<actix_web::app_service::AppEntry>`
   found struct `actix_web::App<impl actix_web::dev::ServiceFactory<actix_web::dev::ServiceRequest, Config = (), Response = actix_web::dev::ServiceResponse<actix_web::body::EitherBody<actix_web::body::BoxBody>>, Error = actix_web::Error, InitError = ()>>` rustc E0308

app.rs(355, 9): the found opaque type

server.rs(13, 23): expected due to this value
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

The error occurs because the variable `app` has a concrete type of `App<AppEntry>` and `app`'s type can never change. But `App::wrap` doesn't return a `App<AppEntry>`, it returns some kind of `App<S>` where `S` is a concrete type but we don't know its name, just what trait(s) it satisfies. Rust calls this an "opaque type".

But because it doesn't have type `App<AppEntry>`, we can't assign it to `app`, hence the error.

Unless `actix_web` has some mechanism to get around this that I'm no aware of, I think your best bet is to factor out the logic for a "wrapped" server into a different function and call that from `start` when needed, something like this:

```
// I just mocked this up to satisfy the compiler
pub struct Config {
    cors_enabled: bool,
    port: u16,
}

pub async fn start(config: Arc<Config>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let addr = SocketAddr::from(([127, 0, 0, 1], config.port));

    if config.cors_enabled {
        return start_with_cors(addr, config).await;
    }

    let server = HttpServer::new(move || App::new());

    server.bind(addr)?.run().await
}

async fn start_with_cors(addr: SocketAddr, _config: Arc<Config>) -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let server = HttpServer::new(move || {
        App::new().wrap(
            Cors::default()
                .allowed_origin("http://localhost:8080")
                .allowed_methods(vec!["GET", "POST"])
                .allowed_headers(vec![header::AUTHORIZATION, header::ACCEPT])
                .allowed_header(header::CONTENT_TYPE)
                .supports_credentials()
                .max_age(3600),
        )
    });

    server.bind(addr)?.run().await
}
```